# Incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat with Gradle 7.0.2

Tags: android, gradle

My app, which was working before, suddenly started crashing in my LaunchActivity with: `Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat`. This is happening with Gradle 7.0.2, which doesn't make sense since other posts regarding this issue are from 3 years ago and recommend updating to gradle 2.0+ (which is much older) and also using the latest android support library (which is a non-issue now with androidx). They also recommend setting `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` which has already been the case in my app. So those posts weren't relevant to my issue.

- minSdkVersion 21
- targetSdkVersion 31
- vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
- implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'

Oddly this started happening on my master after I switched to a different branch and then returned to my master branch after a month. However, the master branch shouldn't have changed at all and it must have been working before, because I cut a production release from it that previous month, and the production release wasn't crashing.

```html
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
      at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.checkVectorDrawableSetup(ResourceManagerInternal.java:495)
      at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:140)
      at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:480)
      at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:93)
      at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachToWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:797)
      at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:773)
      at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:501)
      at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity$2.onContextAvailable(AppCompatActivity.java:131)
      at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable(ContextAwareHelper.java:99)
      at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:297)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:273)
      at com.somewearlabs.sw.ui.LaunchActivity.onCreate(LaunchActivity.kt:14)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed the issue. When I was inspecting the crash in Android Studio, clicking on the file/line number link (eg. "ResourceManagerInternal.java:495") opened up two options for the class, one in appcompat library version `1.2.0` and also `1.3.0`. There must have been two versions used in my dependencies, even though in the build.gradle files for all of my projects explicitly stated `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0`. Using a breakpoint showed that the line in 1.3.0 was getting called when launching the app.

Then I did File > **Invalidate Caches and Restart**.

I thought that ensuring that only one version of appcompat being used in the project might fix things, so I **switched all the build.gradle files from using androidx.appcompat:appcompat `1.2.0` to `1.3.0`**. After resyncing/building, the crash went away. I don't know why this crash started happening in the first place - if anyone could shed some light on this - but I needed to update the appcompat dependency anyway so it worked out.